# Write data to file in columns with commented names

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I am doing some exercises programming in Fortran90 and I have to write data to file in columns with each name of columns commented and I struggled while doing this because my data come from a do while like this

```
do while (a<b)
  k = 2*a - b
  a = a + c
  write(3,100) k,a
end do
100 format ('k',E5.1,X,'a',I2)
```

so when I set format I got *k* and *a* in each line of my data file like

```
k1   a2
k7   a21
k33  a2
```

and I don't know (and haven't found in the book I read) how to write once the name of each column to get a file like

```
k   a
1   2
7   21
33  2
```

Any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You apply the `format` specifier to every line, and consequently get `a` and `k`on each line... You need to first write a header line, and then the data:

```
  write(3,'(a5,1X,a2)') 'k','a'
  do while (a<b)
    k = 2*a - b
    a = a + c
    write(3, '(E5.1,1X,I2)') k,a
  end do
```

Comment: What does mean (a5,1X,a2)? Is a5,a2 the A descriptor for characters?

Comment: This means: five chars, one blank, and another two chars... `a` is indeed for characters.

Comment: So as I have tested early today, format don't distinguishes between lower and upper case. I mean A5 is the same as a5.

Comment: Fortran itself is case-insensitive!